# How can I get a traffic light that exists in sumo and change its phase in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

In sumo, my simulation has a traffic light called `539320442`.

I want that a RSU (that exists in veins) changes this traffic light's phase.

So I created a `Trafficlight`  variable in the `TraCIDemoRSU11p.h`  as it follows:

```
TraCICommandInterface::Trafficlight* RSU_traffic_light;
```

Now I would like to get this traffic light that has id: `539320442` and change its phase by using:

```
void TraCICommandInterface::Traffic_light::setPhase(string, integer)
```

The problem is that in the `TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc` I couldn't get the traffic light and save it in:

```
RSU_traffic_light;
```

So I was wondering how can I get this traffic light and save it in `RSU_traffic_light`:

```
RSU_traffic_light = getTrafficLightbyID("539320442");
```

Would it be something like that? What is the exactly syntax for it?

Comment: you write "part of the code didn't work". Can you elaborate further? What did alternatives did you try? What did you expect would happen? What happened?

Comment: I will edit it again, I found exactly where the main problem is.

Comment: You mention you tried using a method with a signature of `TraCICommandInterface::Traffic_light::setPhase(string, integer)`. No such method exists in Veins. Neither does a class `Traffic_light` exist. Maybe you are going by documentation of different software (maybe the SUMO C++ API?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a traffic light's program and phase is what the simple test application included in Veins 4.5 does. You can refer to [its source code](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCITestApp.cc#L152) to see how it changes traffic light phases:

```
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h"
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h"

TraCIMobility* mobility;
TraCICommandInterface* traci;

mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
traci = mobility->getCommandInterface();
traci->trafficlight("10").setProgram("myProgramGreenRed");
traci->trafficlight("10").setPhaseIndex(1);
```

Note that this uses the SUMO traffic light id and phase id of [the test scenario](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/tests/traci/tls.tls.xml), that is,

```
<tlLogic id="10" type="static" programID="myProgramRed" offset="0">
 <phase duration="999" state="GggGGgrrr"/>
 <phase duration="999" state="GggGGgrrr"/>
</tlLogic>
```

Your scenario will likely use a different traffic light ID and phase ID.